# How to keep page header sticky when soft keyboard shows?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, windows-10-mobile

I have a very simple page with a header and several textboxes in my UWP app:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Page Title!" />

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Margin="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Margin="20" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

In Windows 10 mobile, when the bottom textbox get focus and soft keyboard appears, the full content of the page is scrolling up and I don't want this. I want the header to remain visible and the scrollviewer scrolls to the textbox to keep in view.
How can I achive this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add frame element and add all items except header to that frame then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`CommandBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar) and add the `TextBlock` into `CommandBar.Content`, then the header will remain visible in the page. The page xaml code should look like this,

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar Background="Transparent" OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock  Text="Page Title!" Margin="20" />
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Margin="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Margin="20" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```